# Writing Lines Text File Help, visual c#

Tags: c#, listbox

```
    private void addServerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serverListBox.Items.Add(this.serverTextBox.Text);

        string path = @"C:\\Public Key Pin\UserServerData.txt";
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
        {

            sw.Write(this.serverTextBox.Text);
        }
    }
```

Basically i'm trying to make it so what ever is added to the 'server'ListBox (using a text box and button) is saved in a textfile so the user can 'load' the server list the 2nd time he/she uses the application, but what ever is written into the the list box overwrites the previous item in the text file, so when ever the user loads the server list (serverListBox) it only shows one item (The last item the user added to the ListBox).

How do i make it so it automatically creates a new line in the text file to stop items getting overwritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
private void addServerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    serverListBox.Items.Add(this.serverTextBox.Text);

    string path = @"C:\\Public Key Pin\UserServerData.txt";
    File.AppendAllText(path, this.serverTextBox.Text+"\n");
}
```

If you want load all lines of savefile:

```
// Add all lines to ListBox
serverListBox.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Public Key Pin\UserServerData.txt"));
```

If you want only last line:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Public Key Pin\UserServerData.txt");
// Add last line to ListBox:
if (lines.Length > 0) serverListBox.Items.Add(lines[lines.Length - 1]);
```

Comment: Okay now how to i add the items from the text file to the listbox, i tried:

Comment: StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\\Public Key Pin\UserServerData.txt");
            serverListBox.Items.Add = sr.ReadLine();

Comment: Could you tell me you use WinForms or WPF, I'll write that version for you?

Comment: I use Windows Forms Application

Comment: Thank You! I'd give you all the points if i had enough rep lol

Comment: still need 5 more hah

Answer (score 0):

Use `sw.AppendText(this.serverTextBox.Text);` instead

Answer (score -1):

You should use:

```
        string path = @"C:\\Public Key Pin\UserServerData.txt";
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(this.serverTextBox.Text);
    }
```